# "Magnific Popup" and leaving when hovering a div that opens a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup, magnific-popup

**After closing the popup, the div should be hidden** (and when the pop-up is open it really hides), but when the pop-up is closed, **it becomes visible.**

```js
// Magnific Popup v1.1.0 by Dmitry Semenov
(function(a){typeof define=="function"&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],a):typeof exports=="object"?a(require("jquery")):a(window.jQuery||window.Zepto)})(function(a){var b="Close",c="BeforeClose",d="AfterClose",e="BeforeAppend",f="MarkupParse",g="Open",h="Change",i="mfp",j="."+i,k="mfp-ready",l="mfp-removing",m="mfp-prevent-close",n,o=function(){},p=!!window.jQuery,q,r=a(window),s,t,u,v,w=function(a,b){n.ev.on(i+a+j,b)},x=function(b,c,d,e){var f=document.createElement("div");return f.className="mfp-"+b,d&&(f.innerHTML=d),e?c&&c.appendChild(f):(f=a(f),c&&f.appendTo(c)),f},y=function(b,c){n.ev.triggerHandler(i+b,c),n.st.callbacks&&(b=b.charAt(0).toLowerCase()+b.slice(1),n.st.callbacks[b]&&n.st.callbacks[b].apply(n,a.isArray(c)?c:[c]))},z=function(b){if(b!==v||!n.currTemplate.closeBtn)n.currTemplate.closeBtn=a(n.st.closeMarkup.replace("%title%",n.st.tClose)),v=b;return n.currTemplate.closeBtn},A=function(){a.magnificPopup.instance||(n=new o,n.init(),a.magnificPopup.instance=n)},B=function(){var a=document.createElement("p").style,b=["ms","O","Moz","Webkit"];if(a.transition!==undefined)return!0;while(b.length)if(b.pop()+"Transition"in a)return!0;return!1};o.prototype={constructor:o,init:function(){var b=navigator.appVersion;n.isLowIE=n.isIE8=document.all&&!document.addEventListener,n.isAndroid=/android/gi.test(b),n.isIOS=/iphone|ipad|ipod/gi.test(b),n.supportsTransition=B(),n.probablyMobile=n.isAndroid||n.isIOS||/(Opera Mini)|Kindle|webOS|BlackBerry|(Opera Mobi)|(Windows Phone)|IEMobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent),s=a(document),n.popupsCache={}},open:function(b){var c;if(b.isObj===!1){n.items=b.items.toArray(),n.index=0;var d=b.items,e;for(c=0;c<d.length;c++){e=d[c],e.parsed&&(e=e.el[0]);if(e===b.el[0]){n.index=c;break}}}else n.items=a.isArray(b.items)?b.items:[b.items],n.index=b.index||0;if(n.isOpen){n.updateItemHTML();return}n.types=[],u="",b.mainEl&&b.mainEl.length?n.ev=b.mainEl.eq(0):n.ev=s,b.key?(n.popupsCache[b.key]||(n.popupsCache[b.key]={}),n.currTemplate=n.popupsCache[b.key]):n.currTemplate={},n.st=a.extend(!0,{},a.magnificPopup.defaults,b),n.fixedContentPos=n.st.fixedContentPos==="auto"?!n.probablyMobile:n.st.fixedContentPos,n.st.modal&&(n.st.closeOnContentClick=!1,n.st.closeOnBgClick=!1,n.st.showCloseBtn=!1,n.st.enableEscapeKey=!1),n.bgOverlay||(n.bgOverlay=x("bg").on("click"+j,function(){n.close()}),n.wrap=x("wrap").attr("tabindex",-1).on("click"+j,function(a){n._checkIfClose(a.target)&&n.close()}),n.container=x("container",n.wrap)),n.contentContainer=x("content"),n.st.preloader&&(n.preloader=x("preloader",n.container,n.st.tLoading));var h=a.magnificPopup.modules;for(c=0;c<h.length;c++){var i=h[c];i=i.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+i.slice(1),n["init"+i].call(n)}y("BeforeOpen"),n.st.showCloseBtn&&(n.st.closeBtnInside?(w(f,function(a,b,c,d){c.close_replaceWith=z(d.type)}),u+=" mfp-close-btn-in"):n.wrap.append(z())),n.st.alignTop&&(u+=" mfp-align-top"),n.fixedContentPos?n.wrap.css({overflow:n.st.overflowY,overflowX:"hidden",overflowY:n.st.overflowY}):n.wrap.css({top:r.scrollTop(),position:"absolute"}),(n.st.fixedBgPos===!1||n.st.fixedBgPos==="auto"&&!n.fixedContentPos)&&n.bgOverlay.css({height:s.height(),position:"absolute"}),n.st.enableEscapeKey&&s.on("keyup"+j,function(a){a.keyCode===27&&n.close()}),r.on("resize"+j,function(){n.updateSize()}),n.st.closeOnContentClick||(u+=" mfp-auto-cursor"),u&&n.wrap.addClass(u);var l=n.wH=r.height(),m={};if(n.fixedContentPos&&n._hasScrollBar(l)){var o=n._getScrollbarSize();o&&(m.marginRight=o)}n.fixedContentPos&&(n.isIE7?a("body, html").css("overflow","hidden"):m.overflow="hidden");var p=n.st.mainClass;return n.isIE7&&(p+=" mfp-ie7"),p&&n._addClassToMFP(p),n.updateItemHTML(),y("BuildControls"),a("html").css(m),n.bgOverlay.add(n.wrap).prependTo(n.st.prependTo||a(document.body)),n._lastFocusedEl=document.activeElement,setTimeout(function(){n.content?(n._addClassToMFP(k),n._setFocus()):n.bgOverlay.addClass(k),s.on("focusin"+j,n._onFocusIn)},16),n.isOpen=!0,n.updateSize(l),y(g),b},close:function(){if(!n.isOpen)return;y(c),n.isOpen=!1,n.st.removalDelay&&!n.isLowIE&&n.supportsTransition?(n._addClassToMFP(l),setTimeout(function(){n._close()},n.st.removalDelay)):n._close()},_close:function(){y(b);var c=l+" "+k+" ";n.bgOverlay.detach(),n.wrap.detach(),n.container.empty(),n.st.mainClass&&(c+=n.st.mainClass+" "),n._removeClassFromMFP(c);if(n.fixedContentPos){var e={marginRight:""};n.isIE7?a("body, html").css("overflow",""):e.overflow="",a("html").css(e)}s.off("keyup"+j+" focusin"+j),n.ev.off(j),n.wrap.attr("class","mfp-wrap").removeAttr("style"),n.bgOverlay.attr("class","mfp-bg"),n.container.attr("class","mfp-container"),n.st.showCloseBtn&&(!n.st.closeBtnInside||n.currTemplate[n.currItem.type]===!0)&&n.currTemplate.closeBtn&&n.currTemplate.closeBtn.detach(),n.st.autoFocusLast&&n._lastFocusedEl&&a(n._lastFocusedEl).focus(),n.currItem=null,n.content=null,n.currTemplate=null,n.prevHeight=0,y(d)},updateSize:function(a){if(n.isIOS){var b=document.documentElement.clientWidth/window.innerWidth,c=window.innerHeight*b;n.wrap.css("height",c),n.wH=c}else n.wH=a||r.height();n.fixedContentPos||n.wrap.css("height",n.wH),y("Resize")},updateItemHTML:function(){var b=n.items[n.index];n.contentContainer.detach(),n.content&&n.content.detach(),b.parsed||(b=n.parseEl(n.index));var c=b.type;y("BeforeChange",[n.currItem?n.currItem.type:"",c]),n.currItem=b;if(!n.currTemplate[c]){var d=n.st[c]?n.st[c].markup:!1;y("FirstMarkupParse",d),d?n.currTemplate[c]=a(d):n.currTemplate[c]=!0}t&&t!==b.type&&n.container.removeClass("mfp-"+t+"-holder");var e=n["get"+c.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+c.slice(1)](b,n.currTemplate[c]);n.appendContent(e,c),b.preloaded=!0,y(h,b),t=b.type,n.container.prepend(n.contentContainer),y("AfterChange")},appendContent:function(a,b){n.content=a,a?n.st.showCloseBtn&&n.st.closeBtnInside&&n.currTemplate[b]===!0?n.content.find(".mfp-close").length||n.content.append(z()):n.content=a:n.content="",y(e),n.container.addClass("mfp-"+b+"-holder"),n.contentContainer.append(n.content)},parseEl:function(b){var c=n.items[b],d;c.tagName?c={el:a(c)}:(d=c.type,c={data:c,src:c.src});if(c.el){var e=n.types;for(var f=0;f<e.length;f++)if(c.el.hasClass("mfp-"+e[f])){d=e[f];break}c.src=c.el.attr("data-mfp-src"),c.src||(c.src=c.el.attr("href"))}return c.type=d||n.st.type||"inline",c.index=b,c.parsed=!0,n.items[b]=c,y("ElementParse",c),n.items[b]},addGroup:function(a,b){var c=function(c){c.mfpEl=this,n._openClick(c,a,b)};b||(b={});var d="click.magnificPopup";b.mainEl=a,b.items?(b.isObj=!0,a.off(d).on(d,c)):(b.isObj=!1,b.delegate?a.off(d).on(d,b.delegate,c):(b.items=a,a.off(d).on(d,c)))},_openClick:function(b,c,d){var e=d.midClick!==undefined?d.midClick:a.magnificPopup.defaults.midClick;if(!e&&(b.which===2||b.ctrlKey||b.metaKey||b.altKey||b.shiftKey))return;var f=d.disableOn!==undefined?d.disableOn:a.magnificPopup.defaults.disableOn;if(f)if(a.isFunction(f)){if(!f.call(n))return!0}else if(r.width()<f)return!0;b.type&&(b.preventDefault(),n.isOpen&&b.stopPropagation()),d.el=a(b.mfpEl),d.delegate&&(d.items=c.find(d.delegate)),n.open(d)},updateStatus:function(a,b){if(n.preloader){q!==a&&n.container.removeClass("mfp-s-"+q),!b&&a==="loading"&&(b=n.st.tLoading);var c={status:a,text:b};y("UpdateStatus",c),a=c.status,b=c.text,n.preloader.html(b),n.preloader.find("a").on("click",function(a){a.stopImmediatePropagation()}),n.container.addClass("mfp-s-"+a),q=a}},_checkIfClose:function(b){if(a(b).hasClass(m))return;var c=n.st.closeOnContentClick,d=n.st.closeOnBgClick;if(c&&d)return!0;if(!n.content||a(b).hasClass("mfp-close")||n.preloader&&b===n.preloader[0])return!0;if(b!==n.content[0]&&!a.contains(n.content[0],b)){if(d&&a.contains(document,b))return!0}else if(c)return!0;return!1},_addClassToMFP:function(a){n.bgOverlay.addClass(a),n.wrap.addClass(a)},_removeClassFromMFP:function(a){this.bgOverlay.removeClass(a),n.wrap.removeClass(a)},_hasScrollBar:function(a){return(n.isIE7?s.height():document.body.scrollHeight)>(a||r.height())},_setFocus:function(){(n.st.focus?n.content.find(n.st.focus).eq(0):n.wrap).focus()},_onFocusIn:function(b){if(b.target!==n.wrap[0]&&!a.contains(n.wrap[0],b.target))return n._setFocus(),!1},_parseMarkup:function(b,c,d){var e;d.data&&(c=a.extend(d.data,c)),y(f,[b,c,d]),a.each(c,function(c,d){if(d===undefined||d===!1)return!0;e=c.split("_");if(e.length>1){var f=b.find(j+"-"+e[0]);if(f.length>0){var g=e[1];g==="replaceWith"?f[0]!==d[0]&&f.replaceWith(d):g==="img"?f.is("img")?f.attr("src",d):f.replaceWith(a("<img>").attr("src",d).attr("class",f.attr("class"))):f.attr(e[1],d)}}else b.find(j+"-"+c).html(d)})},_getScrollbarSize:function(){if(n.scrollbarSize===undefined){var a=document.createElement("div");a.style.cssText="width: 99px; height: 99px; overflow: scroll; position: absolute; top: -9999px;",document.body.appendChild(a),n.scrollbarSize=a.offsetWidth-a.clientWidth,document.body.removeChild(a)}return n.scrollbarSize}},a.magnificPopup={instance:null,proto:o.prototype,modules:[],open:function(b,c){return A(),b?b=a.extend(!0,{},b):b={},b.isObj=!0,b.index=c||0,this.instance.open(b)},close:function(){return a.magnificPopup.instance&&a.magnificPopup.instance.close()},registerModule:function(b,c){c.options&&(a.magnificPopup.defaults[b]=c.options),a.extend(this.proto,c.proto),this.modules.push(b)},defaults:{disableOn:0,key:null,midClick:!1,mainClass:"",preloader:!0,focus:"",closeOnContentClick:!1,closeOnBgClick:!0,closeBtnInside:!0,showCloseBtn:!0,enableEscapeKey:!0,modal:!1,alignTop:!1,removalDelay:0,prependTo:null,fixedContentPos:"auto",fixedBgPos:"auto",overflowY:"auto",closeMarkup:'<button title="%title%" type="button" class="mfp-close">&#215;</button>',tClose:"Close (Esc)",tLoading:"Loading...",autoFocusLast:!0}},a.fn.magnificPopup=function(b){A();var c=a(this);if(typeof b=="string")if(b==="open"){var d,e=p?c.data("magnificPopup"):c[0].magnificPopup,f=parseInt(arguments[1],10)||0;e.items?d=e.items[f]:(d=c,e.delegate&&(d=d.find(e.delegate)),d=d.eq(f)),n._openClick({mfpEl:d},c,e)}else n.isOpen&&n[b].apply(n,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1));else b=a.extend(!0,{},b),p?c.data("magnificPopup",b):c[0].magnificPopup=b,n.addGroup(c,b);return c};var C="inline",D,E,F,G=function(){F&&(E.after(F.addClass(D)).detach(),F=null)};a.magnificPopup.registerModule(C,{options:{hiddenClass:"hide",markup:"",tNotFound:"Content not found"},proto:{initInline:function(){n.types.push(C),w(b+"."+C,function(){G()})},getInline:function(b,c){G();if(b.src){var d=n.st.inline,e=a(b.src);if(e.length){var f=e[0].parentNode;f&&f.tagName&&(E||(D=d.hiddenClass,E=x(D),D="mfp-"+D),F=e.after(E).detach().removeClass(D)),n.updateStatus("ready")}else n.updateStatus("error",d.tNotFound),e=a("<div>");return b.inlineElement=e,e}return n.updateStatus("ready"),n._parseMarkup(c,{},b),c}}});var H,I=function(){return H===undefined&&(H=document.createElement("p").style.MozTransform!==undefined),H};a.magnificPopup.registerModule("zoom",{options:{enabled:!1,easing:"ease-in-out",duration:300,opener:function(a){return a.is("img")?a:a.find("img")}},proto:{initZoom:function(){var a=n.st.zoom,d=".zoom",e;if(!a.enabled||!n.supportsTransition)return;var f=a.duration,g=function(b){var c=b.clone().removeAttr("style").removeAttr("class").addClass("mfp-animated-image"),d="all "+a.duration/1e3+"s "+a.easing,e={position:"fixed",zIndex:9999,left:0,top:0,"-webkit-backface-visibility":"hidden"},f="transition";return e["-webkit-"+f]=e["-moz-"+f]=e["-o-"+f]=e[f]=d,c.css(e),c},h=function(){n.content.css("visibility","visible")},i,j;w("BuildControls"+d,function(){if(n._allowZoom()){clearTimeout(i),n.content.css("visibility","hidden"),e=n._getItemToZoom();if(!e){h();return}j=g(e),j.css(n._getOffset()),n.wrap.append(j),i=setTimeout(function(){j.css(n._getOffset(!0)),i=setTimeout(function(){h(),setTimeout(function(){j.remove(),e=j=null,y("ZoomAnimationEnded")},16)},f)},16)}}),w(c+d,function(){if(n._allowZoom()){clearTimeout(i),n.st.removalDelay=f;if(!e){e=n._getItemToZoom();if(!e)return;j=g(e)}j.css(n._getOffset(!0)),n.wrap.append(j),n.content.css("visibility","hidden"),setTimeout(function(){j.css(n._getOffset())},16)}}),w(b+d,function(){n._allowZoom()&&(h(),j&&j.remove(),e=null)})},_allowZoom:function(){return n.currItem.type==="image"},_getItemToZoom:function(){return n.currItem.hasSize?n.currItem.img:!1},_getOffset:function(b){var c;b?c=n.currItem.img:c=n.st.zoom.opener(n.currItem.el||n.currItem);var d=c.offset(),e=parseInt(c.css("padding-top"),10),f=parseInt(c.css("padding-bottom"),10);d.top-=a(window).scrollTop()-e;var g={width:c.width(),height:(p?c.innerHeight():c[0].offsetHeight)-f-e};return I()?g["-moz-transform"]=g.transform="translate("+d.left+"px,"+d.top+"px)":(g.left=d.left,g.top=d.top),g}}}),A()})
```

```css
/* Magnific Popup CSS */

.mfp-bg {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1042;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    background: #0b0b0b;
    opacity: 0.8; }

.mfp-wrap {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1043;
    position: fixed;
    outline: none !important;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }

.mfp-hide {
    display: none !important; }
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!doctype html>
<head>
    <style>
        .div_show {
            height: 33px; width: 198px; background-color: rgb(0, 123, 209);
            position: absolute;
            transition: bottom .3s;
            bottom: -33px;
        }
        .hoverside:hover .div_show{
            bottom: 0px;
        }
        .hoverside {
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            width: 200px;
            height: 150px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .popup{
            width: 400px;
            height:150px;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 40%;
            left: 50%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.popup-content').magnificPopup({
            type: 'inline'
        });
    });
</script>

    <div>
        <div class="hoverside">
            <a href="#popup" class="popup-content">
                <div class="div_show">
                    <p class="link">Click</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div id="popup" class="popup mfp-hide">
                <h3>Popup</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Point to the area, the blue div appears. Make a click. A pop-up window appears and the blue div disappears. Ok, that's what I need. But when you close the pop-up window, the blue div will reappear. How to fix it?

Comment: I think this is because this script sets focus back to the clicked element. If you would be using fancyBox3, then you could simply set `backFocus : false`. (demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bYYGEB). Maybe this script has some similar option.

Comment: @Janis Thanks, it worked in the Magnific Popup too

Answer (score 0):

use the default plugin css.  after that just active the plugin.  then do cuatomize what you need.
here are the repo  http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

Answer (score 0):

If you set to `autoFocusLast: true` last focused element before popup show up will be focused after popup close. You can set `autoFocusLast: false` for hiding the last focused element.

Example demo: https://codepen.io/rubel/pen/ZZQved

See more information: https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#autofocuslast